# how to find the color mix node in the shader editor?

Tags: shader-nodes

Maybe i am too dumb (again) but the search for "color mix" node doesn't work for me:

[image]

what am i doing wrong? or is it a bug?

Of course i know i can find it with the menu...but why or how can i find it in the search? i wanna use the search because it is much faster for me.

Yes, i could use the shortcut A C M ...but i am too old to learn every node shortcut... ;)

Comment: It looks like they have forgotten it

Comment: Isn't it combined with the Mix node with a dropdown to set it to Color nowadays? - There's a 'Mix Color' entry under Search which automatically adds it with the dropdown set to Color mode now. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GAHxtDAsk.

Comment: @JohnEason: you are totally right! if you wanna write an answer...you will get a check and an upvote ;)

Comment: @Chris Too late Gordon got there first! :^)

Comment: yep...but i think he should mention your comment in his answer as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *MixRGB* node as it was called in the *Add* > *Color* menu before (although the node label only shows "Mix") is now deprecated, it does not exist in 3.4 anymore, instead you'll find there a *Mix Color* node which is the general *Mix* node preset to *Color*.

However, if you use the *Node Wrangler* addon, you will still get the old *MixRGB* node: the addon has a shortcut where you can mix two nodes by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and dragging with <kbd>RMB</kbd> from one node to the next. It appears a green connection line and when you release the button, two shaders are plugged into a new *Mix Shader* node:

[image: mixing shader nodes]

This is when you use the shortcut on two *Shader* nodes (the green outputs). But if you use it on two nodes that have *Color* outputs (the yellow ones), no matter if it is an *RGB*, an *Image Texture* or maybe *Noise Texture* node, than the shortcut will connect them with the old *MixRGB* node, although this is nowhere to be found in the *Add* menu:

[image: mixing color nodes]

I don't know how long this will still be functional, but in my 3.4.1 it works. Maybe this changes in future versions.

Comment: maybe you should mention Johns comment too ;)

Comment: @Chris When I started writing my answer (I was interrupted by work), there was no comment... and I knew that without ;) And my answer was more about telling you where the old one is :D

Comment: No worries! Note also that changing the Mix node type in the dropdown also changes the colour of the node header, Blue for Float, Purple for Vector and Teal(?) for Color.

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah I know, I'm familiar with the node and use it quite often. As I said this answer was not really intended to explain the new _Mix_ node, more about informing Chris why he has problems to find the old one and showing a way to get it (although the new one is all fine, no need for the old).